# insertion sort get indices?

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I use the following algorithm for insertion sort:

```
def insertionSort(A):
    indices = [z for z in xrange(len(A))]
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j]
        i = j-1
        while (i>=0) and (A[i]<key):
            A[i+1] = A[i]  
            indices[j-i-1] = i+1         
            i = i-1

        A[i+1] = key
```

However, I need to maintain a list to map the indices of the original values of A  to the sorted values of A, which means if I have a list of [1,3,4,2] after sorting the list = [4,3,2,1] i will have a indices list of [3,1,0,2].

Any pointers? I'm kinda stuck.

**EDITED**: apologies, sorting in descending order..

Comment: Your code sorts in reverse, `[1,3,4,2]` to `[4, 3, 2, 1]` ...

Comment: (1,0), (3,1), (4,2), (2,3) sorted by t[0] gives (1,0), (2,3), (3,1), (4,2), so the indices list should be [0,3,1,2].

Comment: Why is everyone getting that wrong?  It seems clear enough.  It maps from the original positions to the sorted positions, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you writing a sort?  Use Python's builtin sorting.

```
def sort_with_indexes(data):
    sorted_data = sorted(enumerate(data), key=lambda key: key[1])
    indexes = range(len(data))
    indexes.sort(key=lambda key: sorted_data[key][0])
    return [i[1] for i in sorted_data], indexes

data, indexes = sort_with_indexes([1,3,4,2])
print data, indexes
```

Comment: Please, **indices**. You use "indexes" when you say something like "he indexes the records"

Comment: They're both valid.  Welcome to modern English.

Comment: @Glenn Wow, indeed. It still strikes me as extremely odd.

Comment: Python's sort is well-documented as being very efficient for nearly-sorted lists.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out but why use sorted() instead of sort()?

Comment: To use `sort` I'd have to assign `enumerate(data)` to a local first, which I didn't feel was necessary for the code to be clear.  `a.sort` sorts `a`; `sorted(a)` returns a sorted copy of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

the fix to NullUserException's answer is simple:

```
sorted_list, mapping = zip(*sorted([ (v, i) for i, v in enumerate(l) ]))
index_list = [ mapping.index(i) for i in range(len(sorted_list)) ]
```

just replace the call to sorted with your sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `A[i+1]=key`, clearly `indices[j]=i+1`.  However, when you set `A[i+1]=A[i]` You must increment the value of the element of `indices` that has the *value* `i` (because the element of `A` that was at `i` is now at `i+1`).  Unfortunately, I think the naive implementation of this algorithm will be O(n^3) in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your idea of changing the indices array while changing the original in order to keep track of them should work.  I find that when I sometimes have trouble tracking two indices at once and I'll often resort to stepping through the loop(s) on paper to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your version slightly. It now sorts the list A in place (non descending) and returns a list with the "sorted indices".

```
def insertionSort(A):
    sorted_indices = [0]
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        sorted_indices.append(j)
        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            sorted_indices[i+1] = sorted_indices[i]
            i -= 1
        A[i+1] = key
        sorted_indices[i+1] = j
    return sorted_indices
```

Comment: This gives `[0, 3, 1, 2]`, which we've already established is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem, but I was sorting arrays rather than lists.  The problem with using sorted was that it returns a list, which for my purposes took up too much memory.  Luckily, you can do this with numpy using arrays and argsort:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([1,3,4,2])
p=a.argsort()
```

Which will give array([0,3,1,2]) as a result.  This is sorted low to high.